# Can Context Swtich before pause() cause to miss signal?

Tags: linux, signals, posix, semaphore

Consider the following code:

Process A (At random point in time):

```
void catch(){}; // empty handler.

signal(SIGCHLD,&catch); // attach empty handler.
doSomthing();
unlock_semaphore(0);
pause();
```

Process B (Currently blocked with semaphore 0)

```
lock_semaphore(0) // Stuck here until process A unlock 0.
doSomthing();
kill(Process A, SIGCHLD);
```

And consider this sequence of events:

```
(0)A:doSomthing
(1)A:unlock
<--------------- Content Switch from A to B.
(2)B:lock
(3)B:doSomthing
(4)B:kill
<--------------- The signal is handled here (Doing nothing).
(5)A:pause()
<--------------- Process A being suspended indefinitely.
```

So,
Can the following sequence of event happen and thus missing the signal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that can happen.  Instead of using `pause` use [sigsuspend](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigsuspend.2.html) which atomically unblocks the signal, waits for the signal like pause, and then blocks it again.  (This presumes you blocked the signal already because otherwise this scenario can happen at any point in your sequence.)